# How to set a computer's primary DNS-Suffix under Windows Server 2012 Core?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

On a Windows Server 2012 Core installation, how do you set the computer's primary DNS-Suffix.
I do not mean the list of dns suffixes to search on a connection, but the setting that can be changed alongside with the computer's hostname in the gui versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples...

```
reg.exe add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v "NV Domain" /t REG_SZ /d "your_suffix" /f
```

Comment: Uh, don't quite know if I would call that "simple"! Correct maybe, but not simple.

Comment: Does this require a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

When you press [WinKey]+[Pause/Break] it brings up your system info box.  As you can see in there your Primary DNS Suffix is wrong and you want to change it....

1. Close the system info box.
2. Open `DNS Manager GUI`.
3. Delete all forward and reverse lookup zones that deal with the domain name (yes even the _msdcs one).
4. Close `DNS Manager` GUI.
5. Open `regedit` ([WinKey]+r, type "regedit", press enter).
6. Browse to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters`.
7. Change `Domain` key to the new correct domain value.
8. Change `NV Domain` key to the new correct domain value.
9. Close regedit.
10. Check system box again to see that the new suffix is correct now.
11. Reboot server.
12. Open `DNS Manager` GUI.
13. Create new forward DNS zone for `_msdcs.mynewdomain.local`.
14. Restart DNS Server service.
15. Run `ipconfig /flushdns`.
16. Run `ipconfig /registerdns`.
17. Run `net stop netlogon`.
18. Run `net start netlogon`.
19. Wait about 2-5 minutes for the `_msdcs` subdomain to rebuild completely then you should be able to refresh and see a bunch of records that populated inside it.
20. Now your SOA records, etc should have the correct domain suffix.
21. Create new forward DNS zone for `mynewdomain.local`.
22. Create new reverse DNS zone for your subnet (if your server's IP address is 10.23.5.1 then you need to create a reverse dns zone of 10.23.5.x).
23. Go back to the primary forward DNS zone `mynewdomain.local` and dig down to the DNS `A` record that is in there with the server's IP address then double click it to open it up and edit it.
24. Uncheck `Update associated pointer (PTR) record`, then press `Apply`.
25. Check `Update associated pointer (PTR) record`, then press `OK`.

At this point all should be good!